# APACHE POI: Applying formula to a range of cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there a way to apply a formula to the cell range using Java with Apache POI?

I have 6 columns: SL.NO, EMI, Principal O/s at the beginning, Interest, Repayment, Balance at the end.

I know how to create a formula for a single cell. I cannot use the same as I have to generate the values for 60 rows. I am unable to figure it out using loops. Can you help me? Thank you.

Below figure shows the formulae for each column:

[image: table containing formula for the cells]
Below is the code I wrote so far:

```
String interest = "IPMT(B4/12,A10,B5,-C10)";
for(int rows= 1; rows <= Tenor; rows++)
{
    Row Schedulerow = sheet.createRow(rownumber);
    Cell slno = Schedulerow.createCell(0);
    slno.setCellValue(rows);

    Cell emi = Schedulerow.createCell(1);                   
    emi.setCellFormula("B7");
    emi.setCellStyle(rupeestyle);

    Cell principalBeginning = Schedulerow.createCell(2);
    // principalrepayment.setCellFormula("SUM(B10,-D10)");

    Cell interest = Schedulerow.createCell(3);
    // interest.setCellFormula(interest);

    Cell principalrepayment = Schedulerow.createCell(4);
    // principalrepayment.setCellFormula("SUM(B10,-D10)");

    Cell balanceend = Schedulerow.createCell(5);
    // balanceend.setCellFormula("SUM(C10, -E10)");

}
```

Comment: So you want to dynamically construct a formula? It looks to me like your formula in `C` is `"=F" + (rows - 1)`, and that you can likewise use `rows` to construct a formula in columns `D`, `E` and `F`.

Comment: Thank you and Yes. The formula for Column 'C' has worked perfectly. However, the functions used for the other columns are accepting only a range. Is there any other way?

Comment: All the ranges you use are single-cell ranges. In fact, you don't need the `SUM()` formula in columns E and F; you could instead express it as `=B10-D10`. In either case, you can build a formula in Java using string concatenation as above.

Comment: I built a formula using concatenation as you said. It looks something like this: "IPMT(B4/12,A"+(rows)+",B5,-C"+(rows)+")". It worked. Thanks a lot.